# Disabling Menu in MainForm from Second Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, menu

How do I re-enable a `Menu` in MainForm from Second Form?

I use

```
 private void AnalysisForm_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    HomeForm.checkBeamToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
 }
```

But it says

> HomeForm.checkBeamToolStripMenuItem is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level

I'm not sure which part of my code should I declare as `Public`.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what you need to make public: `HomeForm.checkBeamToolStripMenuItem`.

Comment: Hi Cody I just changed my Modifier menu into public and now i'm getting this    "CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HomeForm.checkBeamToolStripMenuItem"    How do I provide static method in my coding? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

protection level for your **checkBeamToolStripMenuItem** in **MainForm** will be **private** by default, you need to make that as **public or internal** so that it could be accessed in other classes,

to make your control public,
**select your control -> properties -> modifier ( change it to public from private )**

and you need to pass the current instance of your Mainform to Second Form and access the control through that instance.

Comment: Now my modifier is internal/public tried both. I got this error   "CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'HomeForm.checkBeamToolStripMenuItem"

Comment: you can fix this in 2 ways,
01) initialize the control in your HomeForm Constructor if the control is added through code,
02) or you can remove your code from cs and drag menustrip control from tools in the designer and do not forget to update the modifier.